# Sencha touch 1 - Left Slide Menu

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I am trying to do some enhancements on an existing app developed using sencha touch.The app was fully developed in Sencha Touch and the new change is to add a Left slide menu like in Facebook app.Is there any plugin developed for Sencha touch 1.I found a lot of plugins for Sencha Touch version >2.0.Because of some time constraints I cannot upgrade the code to latest version now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this you can use Ext.Menu and mount it on the left or right side. You don't need third party library for this feature it is already included in Sencha Touch.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Menu